# javascript method to check form submition with two or more submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

In my web page i using two two submit button in single form submit and save .with the submit button i want to check some validation onsubmit of form and another save button used to submit the data as it is no need to validate that data is there any javascript method to check which submit is clicked.thanks in advanced.

```
   <?php include(ADMIN_HEADER) ?>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <body>
    <section class="account-container register">
    <section class="content clearfix">

        <form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm();" name="registration" enctype="multipart/form-data">


            <h3>STUDENT ENROLLMENT FORM</h3><br>
            <section class="login-fields">
            <?php
                if(isset($message))
                {
                    ?>
                    <script>
                        alert ("<?php echo $message;?>");
                    </script>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>  
                <section class="emp">
                    <p><b>PERONAL DETAILS</b></p>
                    <section class="field">
                        <label>Full Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required class="login1" title="First Name: Only Character" autocomplete="off" >
                        <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required class="login1_1" title="Last Name: Only Character" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="father_name">Father's Name</label>
                        <input name="father_name" placeholder="Father's Name" class="login" title="Father's Name: Only Character" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="dob">Date Of Birth</label>
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker_1" class="login1" placeholder="Date of Birth" required name='dob'>

                        <label for="blood_group">Blood Group</label>

                        <select name="blood_group" class="login1_1" style="margin-left:4%;width:130px" title="Blood Group">
                            <option selected="selected" value="">Blood Group</option>
                            <option value="O+">O+</option>
                            <option value="O-">O-</option>
                            <option value="A+">A+</option>
                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                            <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                            <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                       </select>
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
         <input name="email" placeholder="Email" required class="login" title="Email : abc@gmail.com" autocomplete="off" type="email">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
         <input name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="login" title=" Password" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="mobile">Mobile No</label>
                        <input name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile No" required class="login1" title="Mobile No.:Only Number" maxlength="12" min="10" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                        <label for="alt_mobile">Alternate Mobile No.</label>
                        <input name="alt_mobile" placeholder="Alternate Mobile No." class="login1_1" title="Alternate Mobile No.:Only Number" maxlength="12" min="10" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="qualification">Qualification</label>
                        <input name="qualification" placeholder="Qualification" required class="login" title="Qualification" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="address1">Address 1</label>
                        <textarea name="address1" placeholder="Address 1" required class="login" cols="63" rows="5" title=""></textarea>
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="address2">Address2</label>
                        <textarea name="address2" placeholder="Address 2" class="login" cols="50" rows="5" title=""></textarea>
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                       <span class="txtphoto"> Photograph</span>
                        <input required name="photo" id="photoId" class="loginphoto" title="Photo:Only Image" type="file">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->

                </section>

                <section class="emp_2">
                    <p><b>EDUCATION DETAILS</b></p>
                     <section class="field">
                        <label for="user_id">DEGREE</label>
        <input placeholder="Degree" name="degree" required class="login" title="Degree" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->

                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="company">COLLEGE  </label>
                        <input name="college" placeholder="College Name" required class="login" title="College Name" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="company">RESULT %</label>
                        <input name="result" placeholder="Result %" required class="login" title="Result %" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                     <section class="field">
                        <a href="">Add More</a>
                     </section>
                    <p>
                        <b>ENROLLMENT DETAILS</b>
                    </p>
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="user_id">Course</label>
        <input placeholder="Course" name="course" required class="login1" title="Course" autocomplete="off" type="text">

                      <input name="course_code" placeholder="Course Code" class="login1_1" title="Course code" maxlength="12" min="10" autocomplete="off" type="text">  
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="doj">Starting Date</label>
                       <input name="starting_date" id='datepicker_2' placeholder="Starting Date" required class="login1" title="DOS : dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                       <input name="complition_date" id="datepicker_3" placeholder="Complition Date" required class="login1_1" title="Complition date" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                       </section>                       

                       <section class="field">
                        <label for="doj">Batch Time</label>
                        <input name="batch_start_time" placeholder="Batch Start Time" required class="login1" title="Batch Time" autocomplete="off" type="text">                 <input name="batch_end_time" placeholder="Batch End Time" required class="login1_1" title="Batch Time" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                        </section>

                       <section class="field">
<label for="Practice_hours">Practice Hours</label>

                        <select name="practice_hours" class="login1_1" style="width:150px;" title="Practice Hours">
                            <option selected="selected" value="">Practice Hours</option>
                            <option value="1">1 Hour</option>
                            <option value="2">2 Hour</option>
                            <option value="3">3 Hour</option>
                            <option value="4">4 Hour</option>
                            <option value="5">5 Hour</option>
                       </select>                       

                    <p>
                        <b>PAYMENT DETAIL</b>
                    </p>    
                    <!--<div class="field"><b>Bank Account Detail</b></div> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="bank">Total Amount</label>
                        <input name="total_amount" placeholder="Total Amount" required class="login1" title="Amount"  type="text">
                        <label for="branch">INSTALLMENT</label>
                        <input name="total_installment" placeholder="Total Installment" required class="login1_1" title="Installment" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="Installment paid date">Installment Paid Date</label>
                        <input name="inst_paid_date" id="datepicker_4" placeholder="Installment Paid Date" required class="login1" title="Installment Paid date" autocomplete="off" type="text">

                         <label for="Next Installment Date">Next Installment Date</label>
                        <input type="text" name="next_inst_date" id="datepicker_5" placeholder="Next Installment Date" required class="login1_1" value="" title="Installment : dd-mm-yyyy" autocomplete="off">
                    </section> <!-- /field -->
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="receipt_no">Receipt No</label>
                        <input name="receipt_no" placeholder="Receipt No" required class="login1" title="Receipt No" autocomplete="off" type="text">

                         <label for="Paid Installment">Paid Installment</label>
                        <input type="text" name="paid_installment" placeholder="Paid Installment" required class="login1_1" value="" title="Paid Installment" autocomplete="off">
                    </section> 
                    <section class="field">
                        <label for="counsellor">Counsellor</label>
                        <input name="counsellor" placeholder="Counsellor" required class="login1" title="Counsellor" autocomplete="off" type="text">


                    </section> 
                </section> 
            </section> <!-- /login-fields -->
            <section class="login-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" name="submit">Register</button>
                <button type="reset" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large">Reset</button>
                <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" name="save">Save</button>
            </section> <!-- .actions -->
        </form>
    </section> <!-- /content -->
</section> <!-- /account-container -->



        <!-- /footer -->
        <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->



<script src="Registration_files/jquery-ui.js"></script><script src="Registration_files/registration.js"></script></body></html>
   <?php include(ADMIN_FOOTER) ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide us a snippet of this problem?

Comment: What prevents the user from always clicking on the second button even if there needs to be some validation done?

Comment: If It's done on single submit button. Why you want to do that?

Comment: onsubmit of form its call javascript function validate,and here i used 2 submit so when i click on Register button validateForm() will be called and when click on save again it will call validateForm() for validation checking that i donot want .so is there any method to check whioch submit is clicked so i can use that method to identifying the submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a button instead of a submit when you need validation

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Register" onclick="validateAndSubmit();" />

function validateAndSubmit()
{
    //validate form here
    if(valid)
    {
       document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
    }
    else
    {
       //tell them what to fix
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the required in all the fields and it also showing me an alert on click of save .and i want the required alert on submit only not on save any solution for this

Comment: I am not sure that you can use two submits and use the required attribute the way you are wanting.  Maybe you can leave the button you want to validate as a submit and change the other to a button like this...

    `<input type="button" value="save" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();" />`

this should only call the validation when you use the submit button, not the save button